# How to save Google map with pinned locations?

Tags: google-maps

I have created a new map in which I pinned (with markers) various places for my vacation. I would like to find out how to save it for offline use. How to do so?

Edit: as it turns out, you need to use app "Google maps engine" in order to access your maps.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the image and don't need the underlying data, you can take a screen grab and print it out.

If you need all the data, you could download Google Earth, which I think still provides the offline functionality you're looking for. http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html

To get everything on your device, you can make yourself a map with multiple destinations, then use the gear icon in the lower right corner of Maps to share the link to yourself. From there, you'll get a URL that you can send to your device.

Comment: I need to save those places to my android device with information (addresses, etc.). Image is not enough.

Comment: Another workaround added above.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option within that little gear icon in the lower right corner called *Share and embed map*.

There you can copy and paste the full URL, pins and everything included.

[image]